# I want to export my html table to an xlsx file but the formatting is screwed

Tags: reactjs, export-to-excel, xlsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

export default function AnnualReporTest() {

    const thStyles = {
        border: '1px solid black',
        padding: '10px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    };

    const exportToExcel = () => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('report-table'));

        ws['!cols'] = [{ wch: 20 }, { wch: 20 }, { wch: 20 },{ wch: 20 }, { wch: 20 }, { wch: 20 },{ wch: 10 }, { wch: 10 }, { wch: 15 },{ wch: 15 }, { wch: 15 }]

        const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Report');
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'report.xlsx');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={exportToExcel}>Export to Excel</button>
            <div>
                <table id="report-table">
                <tr>
                    <th style={thStyles}>Firstname</th>
                    <th style={thStyles}>Lastname</th>
                    <th style={thStyles}>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style={thStyles}>Jill</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>Smith</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>50</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={thStyles}>First Budgetary Requirement</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={thStyles}>Second Budgetary Requirement</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style={thStyles}>Eve</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>Jackson</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>94</td>
                    <td style={thStyles}>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={thStyles}>First Budgetary Requirement</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={thStyles}>Second Budgetary Requirement</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br/>
            Hello World!
        </div>
    );
}
```

[this is how it looks like in my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H170Z.png)[this is the exported xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn8tL.png)

I tried to use nested tables so that certain cells are split into different rows. All is well and good in the frontend but converting the html table into xlsx seemed to ruin the format of the tables. I used XLSX library.

Comment: Could you explain the relevant details of the code snippet, as well as the problems with the results?
Basically, explain what you mean by the format being 'screwed' in more technical terms.

Comment: It seems that you have three headers, but each row has four cells, with the fourth cell being another table. How is this meant to look in xlsx?

Comment: @Soenderby Site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H170Z.png XLSX: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn8tL.png

Comment: Yes, I have looked at these pictures. The xlsx in the second image is what it currently looks like. I would like an example of what it is supposed to look like. The problem is stated in the answer below (more cells than headers), but it is not clear how it should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal that it is looking so strange. You have defined 3 headers ( your `<th>` tags) and have defined 4 cells ( `<td>` ) . Excel doesn´t know where to add the data and just adds it in the first cell. You should add another header and the problem should be fixed :

```
 <tr>
                <th style={thStyles}>Firstname</th>
                <th style={thStyles}>Lastname</th>
                <th style={thStyles}>Age</th>
                <th style={thStyles}>Requirement</th>
 </tr>
```